# Google Maps: get coordinates on touch

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to find the coordinates of a point when I touch the google map, but so far everything I have done is not working. Ideally, I want to be able to get the coordinates of a point on the map when i click it. Then after, I would be able to put a pin on the location.

I tried other attempts like:

```
- (void)longpressToGetLocation:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer        
{
if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    return;

CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.mapView];   
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = 
    [self.mapView convertPoint:touchPointtoCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];

NSLog(@"Location found from Map: %f %f",location.latitude,location.longitude);

}
```

but this would not work and i got an error saying 
"no visible @interface for gmsmapview declares the selector convertpoint tocoordinatefromview.

I am kind of lost and not sure what to do.

Best,
J

Answer (score 0):

The google maps gives you a delegate when tapped at a point. The way you get these events is,

You conform your class to `GMSMapViewDelegate` and implement the method: `- mapView:didTapAtCoordinate:`. Make sure you set the delegate of the `mapview` to `self`.

You can find all about `GMSMapViewDelegate` [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p#a9f226252840c79a996df402da9eec235).

Answer (score 0):

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [self setUpGesture:YES];
}

- (void)setUpGesture:(BOOL)state
{
    if (state == YES)
    {
        self.longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                       action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
        self.longPress.delegate = self;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.longPress];

    }
    else
    {
        [self.mapView removeGestureRecognizer:self.longPress];
        self.longPress = nil;
    }

}

- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        CGPoint longPressPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
        [self dropPinAtPoint:longPressPoint];
    }
}


- (void)dropPinAtPoint:(CGPoint)pointToConvert
{
touchMapCoordinate = [self.mapView convertPoint:pointToConvert
                               toCoordinateFromView:self.view];
}

{


                NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",touchMapCoordinate.latitude] forKey:@"latitude"];
                [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",touchMapCoordinate.longitude] forKey:@"longitude"];
                [dict setObject:Str_pin forKey:@"title"];

                [ApplicationDelegate.Array_LongpressItem addObject:dict];


                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:ApplicationDelegate.Array_LongpressItem forKey:@"ApplicationDelegate.Array_LongpressItem"];


                    for (id annotation in self.mapView.annotations)
                                        {
                                            [self.mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];

                                        }


                [self loadRoute];

                // add the overlay to the map
                if (nil != self.routeLine) {
                    [self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
                }

                // zoom in on the route.
                [self zoomInOnRoute];


                for (int i=0; i<[ApplicationDelegate.Array_LongpressItem count]; i++)
                {
//                    NSString *pinTitle = Str_pin;
//                    // NSString *subCoordinates = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f, %f", convertedPoint.latitude, convertedPoint.longitude];
//                    
//                    MyAnnotation *point = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
//                    point.coordinate = touchMapCoordinate;
//                    point.tag=[NSNumber numberWithInt:2000];
//                    point.title = pinTitle;
//                    
//                    //    for (id annotation in self.mapView.annotations)
//                    //    {
//                    //        [self.mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
//                    //
//                    //    }
//                    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];

                    CLLocationDegrees latitude  = [[[ApplicationDelegate.Array_LongpressItem objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue];
                    CLLocationDegrees longitude = [[[ApplicationDelegate.Array_LongpressItem objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"longitude"]floatValue];
                    // create our coordinate and add it to the correct spot in the array
                    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
                    ann[i] = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
                    ann[i].coordinate =coordinate;
                    ann[i].tag=[NSNumber numberWithInt:2000];
                    ann[i].title = [[ApplicationDelegate.Array_LongpressItem objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"];
                    [_mapView addAnnotation:ann[i]];

                }
            }

- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(MyAnnotation*) annotation
{
if ([annotation.tag intValue]==2000)
    {
        annView.annotation=annotation;
        annView.canShowCallout = YES;
        UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        annView.animatesDrop=YES;
        button1.tag=[annotation.tag intValue];
        [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btn_clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView =  button1;
        annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 32);

    }
}
```